# How to reach element inside of another element in selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

i'm using selenium webdriver
i'm trying to reach that " Veuillez valider le test reCAPTCHA.. "in this source code:

```html
<div id="rc-anchor-container" class="rc-anchor rc-anchor-normal rc-anchor-light"><div id="recaptcha-accessible-status" class="rc-anchor-aria-status" aria-hidden="true">Veuillez valider le test reCAPTCHA..</div><div class="rc-anchor-error-msg-container" style="display:none"><span class="rc-anchor-error-msg" aria-hidden="true"></span></div><div class="rc-anchor-content"><div class="rc-inline-block"><div class="rc-anchor-center-container"><div class="rc-anchor-center-item rc-anchor-checkbox-holder"><span class="recaptcha-checkbox goog-inline-block recaptcha-checkbox-unchecked rc-anchor-checkbox" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" id="recaptcha-anchor" tabindex="0" dir="ltr" aria-labelledby="recaptcha-anchor-label"><div class="recaptcha-checkbox-border" role="presentation"></div><div class="recaptcha-checkbox-borderAnimation" role="presentation"></div><div class="recaptcha-checkbox-spinner" role="presentation"><div class="recaptcha-checkbox-spinner-overlay"></div></div><div class="recaptcha-checkbox-checkmark" role="presentation"></div></span></div></div></div><div class="rc-inline-block"><div class="rc-anchor-center-container"><label class="rc-anchor-center-item rc-anchor-checkbox-label" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation" id="recaptcha-anchor-label"><span aria-live="polite" aria-labelledby="recaptcha-accessible-status"></span>Je ne suis pas un robot</label></div></div></div><div class="rc-anchor-normal-footer"><div class="rc-anchor-logo-portrait" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation"><div class="rc-anchor-logo-img rc-anchor-logo-img-portrait"></div><div class="rc-anchor-logo-text">reCAPTCHA</div></div><div class="rc-anchor-pt"><a href="https://www.google.com/intl/fr/policies/privacy/" target="_blank">Confidentialité</a><span aria-hidden="true" role="presentation"> - </span><a href="https://www.google.com/intl/fr/policies/terms/" target="_blank">Conditions</a></div></div></div>
```

here is the website its a simple website   https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo
i wanna reach the text above  in the captcha field
i tried reaching it by id but it didnt print the text
itried to reach the bigger element then reach the small one but it didnt wrk

```html
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

PATH ="C:\Program Files (x86)/chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo")
time.sleep(10)
try:
   nom = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="recaptcha-demo-form"]/fieldset/ul/li[1]/label'))   
    )
   print(nom.text)
   h = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "recaptcha-accessible-status"))   
    )
   
   print(h.text)
   
except:
    driver.close()
```

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first snippet you provided has just text, and the DOM is small, and just the ID would take you to the element.

`captcha = driver.find_element(By.ID, "recaptcha-accessible-status")`

[DOM Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGIMH.png)

I hit the website you showed in the link, and it shows to me in English. Here the DOM is relatively larger than the first snippet one.

`driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//form[@id='recaptcha-demo-form']//legend"]` This should take you to the text.

[DOM Snapshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJJq7.png)

If you are trying to get to the CAPTCHA checkbox, then you have to switch to iframe first and then access the element, as it lies inside an iframe.

```
frame = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//iframe[@title='reCAPTCHA'])
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
#your code here
# to come back to parent window,use:
driver.swtich_to.default_content()
```

[iframe DOM Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWDuH.png)